# How to reset a Live Ubuntu 12.04 Usb so that I install tails instead

Tags: upgrade, usb, uninstall

I currently have a Live USB with Ubuntu 12.04 on it and my Laptop is a Windows 10 machine.

I would like to remove Ubuntu 12.04 and use Tails instead. The reason I want to use Tails is that I am planning on storing my Cryptocurrency Wallets on Tails and tails is recommended for this due it having Electrum.

If Tails is not necessary for this can you please let me know how I can upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu safely without damaging my Windows 10 OS.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry most of this is offtopic. To install another operating system you do not need the current system except for a generic method to install the installer of that new OS.  If you want to install "Tails" visit their website and look for installation instructions. But that is not a Ubuntu system not something for us. "how I can upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu safely without damaging my Windows 10 OS." see https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, I thought Ubuntu deal with tails as well. Thaks for providing other answer. Can you tell me do i need to remove Ubuntu before Installing tails

Comment: No. And I doubt you even need to install tails on your hard disk (it can be used as a live session from an USB) If you do: it is also possible to triple boot or to install virtualbox and tails inside Ubuntu or even inside Windows.

Comment: I don't want to install tails on hard disk. i want to put it on the USB that currently has Ubuntu. I don't know anything about triple boot. I have Virtualbox on my laptop. Does tails need to be inside Ubuntu or windows. Can it be put inside a VM on its own without Ubuntu/Windows

Comment: Are you asking how to make a multiboot live USB, or do you simply want to replace the current Ubuntu live OS on the USB with a different distro? if the latter, just format the USB and burn the new bootable ISO of your choice to it - if you enabled persistence, then remember to back up any personal data first.

Comment: Replace. To format do i use Diskpart or will burn process do the formatting for me. thanks for reply

Comment: Format your USB drive and do a fresh install of Tails to it. If you used SDC to install Ubuntu you may need mkusb to wipe it first, Peruse the Tails documentation page: https://tails.boum.org/doc/index.en.html . Tails is derived from Debian just like Ubuntu but setup can be complex, Peruse documentation a second time as you are playing with money. Ignore the "Duplicated" question, the people that marked your question as duplicate did not understand your question, as is often the case.

Comment: Come on  @Rinzwind, N0rbert, Charles Green, Eric Carvalho, LnxSlck, et al. What does your duplicated question about upgrading Ubuntu have to do with installing a secure Linux version for Cryptocurrency storage? Please read the questions before shouting "Duplicate".

Comment: Ive contacted Tails and awaiting reply on how to remove ubuntu. I think i used linuxliveusb.com creator to do the Ubuntu install. How do I actually do the formatting?

Comment: Tails replied. They said I can just install the new Ubuntu over the old. I dont need to format the usb or remove old Ubuntu beforehand